# Editing ArcSDE table with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, editing

The link below provides a code snippet for editing an ArcSDE table with ArcObjects.

Are there any other or newer code examples out there of how to edit an ArcSDE table by using ArcObjects?

[Edit SDE geodatabase table w/ ArcObjects](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=985&t=97308)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a few to get you started:

[Start Here - Learning ArcObjects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Learning_ArcObjects/0001000000p1000000/)

[Connecting to a GeoDatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000003s8000000.htm)

[Creating and Modifying Schema](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_and_modifying_schema/000100000mv5000000/)

[Versioning](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Versioning/000100000mq1000000/)

[Editing Data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Editing_with_the_geodatabase_API/00010000010s000000/)

And in specific you can look at [Creating Features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_features/00010000049v000000/) and [Updating Features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Updating_features/0001000002rs000000/).  Both of these will require you to connect to your GeoDatabase, which you can find samples for above.